# Deserializing LocalDate from RavenDB to object

Tags: .net, ravendb

I need to persist `LocalDate` (from NodaTime) in RavenDB. The object it's represented by is `IDictionary<string, object>`. Saving works fine (with a little help from https://github.com/ryanheath/RavenDB-NodaTime), but loading returns `string`. Is there a way to get `LocalDate` (boxed into `object`, obviously) on loading?

Answer (score 2):

You would need to customize the JsonSerializer and add a new converter for this.

You can take a look on following examples:

https://github.com/ravendb/ravendb/blob/v4.2/test/SlowTests/Issues/RavenDB_12194.cs#L22

https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/4.2/csharp/client-api/configuration/serialization#conventions-serialization

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for something less involved though. Customizing (de)serialization is just not worth it in this case.